# Does the identity theorem hold when both functions have an essential singularity at an accumulation point?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The classical identity theorem is the following:

> **Theorem:** Let $f,g:D\to\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the domain $D$. If $f=g$ on a non-discrete subset of $D$, then $f=g$ on $D$.

For concreteness, let's suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both holomorphic on the punctured unit disk $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$, and that $f=g$ on the set $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq2\}$. Further suppose that $f$ and $g$ both have an essential singularity at $0$. Does it follow that $f=g$ on $\mathbb{D}$?

Note that if we change "essential singularity" to "pole of order $m$", then the answer is affirmative - apply the identity theorem to the holomorphic functions $z^mf(z)$ and $z^mg(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative. Consider the following two functions:
$$f(z)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)e^{1/z},\,g(z)=z\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)e^{1/z}.$$
We have that $f=g$ on $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N},n\geq2\}$ since both functions vanish on this set. Further, both functions have an essential singularity at $0$ due to the presence of the $e^{1/z}$ term; however, $f\neq g$ on $\mathbb{D}$.